# How are computers that share the same IP address being identified?

Tags: ip

The computers in my office share the same IP address. Having that in mind, how does the Internet know that when I request a file from a remote server, it is exactly my computer that should receive the file and not one of the other computers (in my office) that share the same IP address?

Comment: "All the computers in my office use the same IP address." No they don't. You can't have two machines on the same segment with the same IP address without a *lot* of trickery.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he meant "the same IP address" as viewed from the Internet point of view.

Comment: @Antoie, That's right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It uses the tuple (source ip, source port, dest port, dest ip).

Therefore it does not identify a computer but a connection and that is all that matters from an Internet-server point of view.

You router then has a table that allows him to know to which computer he needs to forward the connection. This is called [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT).